# Adaptive Icon issue in Oreo

Tags: android

I am using **adaptive icon** for one of my application. I have created adaptive icon using Image Assets. On some devices of Oreo version it is working fine but in Samsung phone it is not showing the correct result.
I have also added `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` attribute to my application tag, and my `any_dpiv26\ic_launcher_round.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/> . 
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

where `<color name="ic_launcher_background">#26A69A</color>`

I have also added the screenshot of one of the devices that it is working. While in Samsung it is not working given below adaptive image, I have tested using an emulator and some other Oreo devices and it is working fine there.

[image: phone screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also faced the same issue in Android Oreo.

> **1) Add your images by adding in Image Vector** ..File -> New - > Image Asset

- don't forget to use **scaling** to adapt your image with **Trim & Resize**

[image]

also you can check this video , it will help you :

[How to Create App Launcher Icon in Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXACM2e0ISE)